# Is there any way in Python 3 to get floats bigger than numpy.float128?

Tags: python, floating-point, precision, bignum

I was trying to make some code that involved giant numbers so I used `numpy.float128`. Though it did help a little, it didn't really help me because the numbers I was using were even too big for that. So is there anything I can do to get numbers with 10,000+ digits? (It also is a float so things that involve `int` won't work for me.)

Comment: Python automatically allows you to use an arbitrarily large integer, so converting your decimals to integers through multiplication might be one approach. If you need an arbitrary precision of decimal places you can use the ```decimal``` library. https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html

Comment: In addition to `decimal` which provide an arbitrary precision floating point type the is also the [`fractions`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html) module.

Comment: IIRC float128 is just a long double with some padding.

Comment: @sintribu Please don't post answers in the comments, post an answer instead. I'd upvote :)

Comment: @sintribu that really helped thank you